# Can I have a per-directory setting for where swap files are stored?

Tags: swap-file

I’m usually fine with swap files being created in the same directory as the files being edited—I have the [`directory`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27directory%27) setting left on its default value. I have one project, though, with “file watching” functionality that gets confused by swap files.

I notice that `directory` is a global setting (i.e. you can’t set it on a per-buffer basis). Is there some workaround so that I can change where swap files are put *only* when I’m editing files within a certain directory?

Comment: Usually, "file watching" tools have a mean to ignore files or file patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to edit those files only, using a separate instance of vim, you can do a `vim -n <filename>` which tells vim to use memory only, no swap files for editing.

Alternatively, you could create a `.vimrc` file in that particular directory, containing the following:

```
source ~/.vimrc
directory=~/tmp
```

then start vim within that directory via `vim -u <vimrc> <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thought this 100% through, but maybe you could look into it.

Why not do a chain of autocomands, where `BufWinEnter` adds a `WinEnter` autocommand, which in turn changes `directory` and stores the original value in a buffer-local variable, and a `WinLeave` aoutocommand that changes it back, and a `BufWinLeave` au. that removes the previous two? It's kind of a mess, but if you do it right, it should work well.

(please tell me if this needs further explaining)

EDIT: I just realized this depends on whether or not vim cares about swap files of bufers you aren't currently editing, so it really comes down to testing. If you're willing to spend the, I don't know, probably no more than 30 minutes to try it, please be sure to tell us if it works :)